# Stanford NER is ready in localhost, how to push it to a live server?

Tags: php, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

I am pretty new to Java. I wrote my NER script with php as shown below:

```
require './src/StanfordNLP/Base.php';
require './src/StanfordNLP/Exception.php';
require './src/StanfordNLP/Parser.php';
require './src/StanfordNLP/StanfordTagger.php';
require './src/StanfordNLP/NERTagger.php';
$pos = new \StanfordNLP\NERTagger(
  'C:/xampp_new/htdocs/stanford-ner-2015-04-20/classifiers/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',
'C:/xampp_new/htdocs/stanford-ner-2015-04-20/stanford-ner.jar'
);            

$text= "The Federal Reserve Bank of New York led by Timothy R. The electricity was not discovered by Alexander Graham bell";

$text = str_replace(".",",",$text);

$result = $pos->tag(explode(' ', " $text")); 

var_dump($result);
```

But the problem is, i want to push the package to the live server. NER is Java and my script is php.

I tried pushing stanford-ner.jar onto a java hosting and rest of the script onto a apache hosting and then changed the above $pos to:

```
$pos = new \StanfordNLP\NERTagger(
  'C:/xampp_new/htdocs/stanford-ner-2015-04-20/classifiers/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',
'http://www.example.com/stanford-ner.jar'
);
```

It doesn't work. Please help